# Error when initializing the child component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am going crazy with useEffect. I started coding 3 months ago and I am not really experienced.

I have a parent component which initializes some data from database with useEffect then I pass that data as props to a child component which initializes some other data from database with useEffect. I can't make it work no matter what I try. I think that the reason is because component unmounts before the child component's initialization is done. I have been reading documentations but couldn't figure out how to overcome this problem.

I appreciate if you can help me solve it.

```
...
import ModelDesigner from './subComponents/ModelDesigner'

const Model = ({ match }) => {
const [model, setModel] = useState({})

const initialize = async (id) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/model/${id}`)
    setModel(res.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data)
  }
}

const link = match.params.link

useEffect(() => {
  initialize(link)
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
return ( 
<ModelDesigner user={model.user} />
)
```

---

```
...
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const ModelDesigner = ({ user }) => {
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({})

const loadProfile = async (id) => {
  try {
    const profile = await axios.get(`/profile/id/${id}`)
    setProfile(profile.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  loadProfile(user)
}, [])

return ( ... )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, in order to help us to help you, please include reproducible example or code samples.

Comment: I added a screenshot of simplified version of my code

Comment: No screenshots, please. Add it as text. [Reasons not to post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I think problem is happening because of model.user (first it was undefined then anything else) is changing and u are sending it as props. So u should say that to useEffect user is changing. Can you try it with adding a parameter like this 
useEffect(() => {
  loadProfile(user)
}, [user])

Comment: Sorry but couldn't really understand your problem very well , what is not working - The child component is not getting the data through props ?

Comment: Thank you Furkan! You solved the problem. But is there any other effective way to split the main component into small components? In my case, I want to create child components like productImages, comments, relatedProducts and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's going on here. `Model` is initialized asynchronously, so when it's first rendered, the `model` variable is an empty object.

However, the child `ModelDesigner` is rendered right away and its `useEffect` callback runs before the model is loaded from the API. So it's probably calling `/profile/id/undefined` instead of using the profile ID you want.

One way to fix this is to wait on rendering the child component until you've finished loading the data it needs for its props. For this example I guess that would look something like:

```
return model.user
  ? <ModelDesigner user={model.user} />
  : <div />
```

Alternatively, you could add `user` as a dependency for `useEffect` and skip the API call if it's an empty value. That way it'll wait to try to initialize until it has the ID it needs.

```
const loadProfile = async (id) => {
  if (!id) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    const profile = await axios.get(`/profile/id/${id}`)
    setProfile(profile.data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  loadProfile(user)
}, [user])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just put [user] as second parameter in useEffect and it solved my problem. But is there any other effective way to split the main component into small components. In my case, I want to create child components like productImages, comments, relatedProducts and so on...